# Por que desmarcar a criação de classe principal quando trabalhamos com tela?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Até o momento, em todos os tutoriais que vi, quando vamos trabalhar com uma tela swing, é pedido que se desmarque a criação de classe principal.

Eu gostaria de saber a ciência por trás disso, e o que resulta caso eu não o faça de tal forma.

Edit:
Ta na mao, espero que visivel

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Desmarcar o que? Faz tempo que mexo com java-swing e nunca vi isso. Poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: Giovane, tem como mostrar uma _screenshot_ do que você tem que "desmarcar"?

Comment: Claro, já mando a screenshot

Comment: Tranquilo. Apenas note que você precisa [edit] a pergunta para adicionar a screenshot, não precisa fazer outro post =D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não vejo problema algum e fazer isso, não tem nada de errado. O que acontece é que muita gente prefere criar o projeto do zero e todo o controle para si do que ocorre nele, e se você marcar essa opção, a IDE irá criar uma classe principal baseada no nome do projeto, o que nem sempre é o esperado, e o netbeans acabará por definir essa classe como o ponto de partida de execução do projeto.

Além do mais, se você precisar mudar a classe principal posteriormente, terá que mexer nas propriedades do projeto, o que pode não ser tão simples para quem está iniciando.

Mas em resumo, isso não é um problema, se você já sabe qual classe será o ponto de partida da sua aplicação logo na criação do projeto. Se desmarcar essa opção, de qualquer forma, o netbeans irá solicitar que você escolha uma classe principal(se tiver mais de uma com o método main) ao executar o projeto pela primeira vez, e posteriormente você pode renomear esta classe também.